# Can I link lib compiled with vs2005 in C++ Builder 2007?

Tags: c++, hyperlink, c++builder

I compiled google v8 into v8.lib using VS2005. Can I link this in C++ Builder 2007?

Comment: to Eric M: 
I got this error,it seem that v8.lib is a COFF format lib while c++builder expecting a OMF one

[ILINK32 Error] Error: 'E:\DOC\OPENSOURCE\C++\V8\V8.LIB' contains invalid OMF record, type 0x21 (possibly COFF)

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to reuse a .lib from MSVC to C++Bulder. They use a different file format and use different runtime libraries.

Like Victor said make a straight C DLL in MSVC and use a the builder tool (IMPLIB.exe?) to create the stub .lib for C++Builder -or- just rebuild the whole project in builder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  I do it all the time.  What you will need to do is find out the calling convention used within the LIB.  Within your C++ Builder project manager, add the LIB file to the list of source files so the linker knows to include it at link time.  I assume you have the header files that prototype the LIB contents....

Comment: Are you talking about linking a static library built with Visual Studio to Borland C++? I don't believe this is possible because the two tool-chains use completely different object formats under the hood. aztack's comment indicates the trouble one runs into when tried. OTOH linking against a dll with an import stub is possible if it's exposed as a C-library.